# iOS ReactNative: Text not wrapping and displaying off-screen

Tags: ios, react-native

I seem to have a problem with a simple text field.  The text inside is not wrapping.  I'm running on an iOS 5s simulator.  Any ideas?

[image: Text Not Wrapping]

Following the tutorial here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/99473/introducing-react-native-building-apps-javascript

**Styles:**

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
 description: {
   marginBottom: 20,
   fontSize: 18,
  textAlign: 'center',
  color: '#656565',
},
container: {
  padding: 30,
  marginTop: 65,
  alignItems: 'center',
},
```

**Code:**

```
<View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.description}>
          Search for houses to buy!
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.description}>
          Search by place-name, postcode or search near your location!
      </Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Are you using flexbox anywhere above this component, as in a parent component?

Comment: I'm just using the standard ReactNative libs, I don't think I have to explicitly 'require' flexbox or anything?  I'm not using it anywhere other than these two views

Comment: I was asking because when I ran the exact code on rnplayground simulator, the text did wrap, but if you had an outside flex container, you may need to specify the flexWrap property to 'wrap'. https://rnplay.org/apps/x0Xf6w

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran the exact code on rnplayground simulator, but the text did wrap correctly. If you had an outside flex container, you may need to specify the flexWrap property to 'wrap'.

[rnplay.org/apps/x0Xf6w](http://rnplay.org/apps/x0Xf6w)